# Consume Rest API X-pagination from header

Tags: c#, rest, postman, restsharp

How can I extract the `X-Pagination` header from a response and use the next link to chain requests?

I've tried in both Postman and C# console application with RestSharp. No success.

Easiest would be a small console application to test. I just need to iterate through the pages.

This is what I get back in the headers `X-Pagination`:

```
{
  "Page":1,
  "PageSize":20,
  "TotalRecords":1700,
  "TotalPages":85,
  "PreviousPageLink":"",
  "NextPageLink":"www......./api/products/configurations?Filters=productid=318&IncludeApplicationPerformance=true&page=1",
  "GotoPageLinkTemplate":"www..../api/products/configurations?Filters=productid=318&IncludeApplicationPerformance=true&page=0"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postman you simply retrieve the header, parse it into a Json object then use the value to set a link for your next request.

Make your initial request then in the Test tab do something like:

```
var nextPageLinkJson = JSON.parse(pm.response.headers.get("X-Pagination"));
var nextPageLink = nextPageLinkJson.NextPageLink;
pm.environment.set("nextPageLink", nextPageLink);
```

If you don't know how many pages you're going to have then you'll have to play with conditions when to set the `nextPageLink` variable and what not but that's the general idea.

You can set the request to run using the new link with `postman.setNextRequest("request_name")` as well.

Additionally this approach will only work in collection runner.

Comment: Thanks! Solved with this. As easy as it looks i couldn't figure it out :)